# Запрет закрытия окна Qt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Как сделать, чтобы окно приложения не закрывалось по нажатию на крестик?

основной код **main.py**:

```
import os, zipfile
from shutil import rmtree
from time import sleep
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from blockd import Ui_dialog
import sys

#passwd = input(b"")
def unpack():
    pathToArchive = 'C:\\Users\\Печка\\Desktop\\разное\\блокировщик код\\d.zip'
    zipArchive = zipfile.ZipFile(pathToArchive, 'r')
    unzippedFile = zipArchive.open('untitled.ui', 'r', passwd.encode('cp850', 'replace'))
    content = unzippedFile.read()
    f = open('C:\\Users\\Печка\\Desktop\\разное\\блокировщик код\\unititled.ui', 'wb')
    f.write(content)
    unzippedFile.close()
    f.close()

def pack():
    pass

def check():
    pass

def desine():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_dialog()
    ui.setupUi(dialog)
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

desine()
```

код файла **blockd.py**:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'blockd.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.2
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, dialog):
        dialog.setObjectName("dialog")
        dialog.resize(400, 300)
        dialog.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 300))
        dialog.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 300))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("opera_gx_browser_logo_icon_152976.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        dialog.setWindowIcon(icon)
        dialog.setStyleSheet("")
        self.passb = QtWidgets.QPushButton(dialog)
        self.passb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(14, 142, 371, 141))
        self.passb.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.OpenHandCursor))
        self.passb.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"font: 30pt;\n"
"background-color: #001aff;\n"
"color: #04ff00;\n"
"border: none\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"background-color: #f80;\n"
"color: #fff\n"
"}")
        self.passb.setObjectName("passb")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 141, 20))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: #04ff00")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.log = QtWidgets.QLabel(dialog)
        self.log.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 80, 221, 51))
        self.log.setStyleSheet("color: #04ff00")
        self.log.setText("")
        self.log.setObjectName("log")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(dialog)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, -10, 411, 321))
        self.textBrowser.setStyleSheet("background-color: #000")
        self.textBrowser.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhHiddenText)
        self.textBrowser.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.textBrowser.setPlaceholderText("")
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(dialog)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 280, 101, 20))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: #04ff00")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.passi = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(dialog)
        self.passi.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 361, 20))
        self.passi.setStyleSheet("color: #04ff00;\n"
"background-color: #001aff;\n"
"border: none")
        self.passi.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.passi.setObjectName("passi")
        self.textBrowser.raise_()
        self.passb.raise_()
        self.log.raise_()
        self.label.raise_()
        self.label_3.raise_()
        self.passi.raise_()

        self.retranslateUi(dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("dialog", "opera locker by lerontick"))
        self.passb.setText(_translate("dialog", "Войти"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("dialog", "Введите пароль:"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("dialog", "автор: lerontick"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приложение можно закрыть не только нажатием на крестик,
а еще и сочетание клавишь `alt+F4`, тоже приведет к закрытию приложения.

Я понял, что вы хотите запустить длительный процесс и чтобы пока он
не закончит работу - окно нельзя никак позволить закрыть.
Если я вас правильно понял, то попробуйте

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, dialog):
        dialog.setObjectName("dialog")
        dialog.resize(400, 300)
        dialog.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 300))
        dialog.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 300))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("opera_gx_browser_logo_icon_152976.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        dialog.setWindowIcon(icon)
        dialog.setStyleSheet("")
        self.passb = QtWidgets.QPushButton(dialog)
        self.passb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(14, 142, 371, 141))
        self.passb.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.OpenHandCursor))
        self.passb.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"font: 30pt;\n"
"background-color: #001aff;\n"
"color: #04ff00;\n"
"border: none\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"background-color: #f80;\n"
"color: #fff\n"
"}")
        self.passb.setObjectName("passb")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 141, 20))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: #04ff00")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.log = QtWidgets.QLabel(dialog)
        self.log.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 80, 221, 51))
        self.log.setStyleSheet("color: #04ff00")
        self.log.setText("")
        self.log.setObjectName("log")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(dialog)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, -10, 411, 321))
        self.textBrowser.setStyleSheet("background-color: #000")
        self.textBrowser.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhHiddenText)
        self.textBrowser.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.textBrowser.setPlaceholderText("")
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(dialog)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 280, 101, 20))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: #04ff00")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.passi = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(dialog)
        self.passi.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 361, 20))
        self.passi.setStyleSheet("color: #04ff00;\n"
"background-color: #001aff;\n"
"border: none")
        self.passi.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.passi.setObjectName("passi")
        self.textBrowser.raise_()
        self.passb.raise_()
        self.log.raise_()
        self.label.raise_()
        self.label_3.raise_()
        self.passi.raise_()

        self.retranslateUi(dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("dialog", "opera locker by lerontick"))
        self.passb.setText(_translate("dialog", "Войти"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("dialog", "Введите пароль:"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("dialog", "автор: lerontick"))


class Thread(QtCore.QThread):
    threadSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal() 
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.num = 1000
        
    def run(self):
        while self.num:                           # имитация вашего длительного процесса
            self.num -= 1
            self.threadSignal.emit(self.num)
            self.msleep(10)
        self.finished.emit()                      # процесс завершен


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.flagClose = False
        self.passb.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        
        # тут ваша логика ... 
        
        
    def onClicked(self):
        self.flagClose = True
        self.passb.setText("Выполняется процесс - ожидайте... ")
        self.passb.setStyleSheet("""
            QPushButton {
                font: 15pt;
                background-color: #001aaa;
                color: #ffff00;
            }
        """)
        
        self.thread = Thread()                     # дополнительный поток для тяжелой задачи
        self.thread.threadSignal.connect(lambda: print(self.thread.num))
        self.thread.finished.connect(self._finished)
        self.thread.start()

    def _finished(self):
        self.passb.setEnabled(False)  
        self.passb.setText("Войти")
        self.passb.setStyleSheet("""
            QPushButton {
                font: 30pt;
                background-color: #001aff;
                color: #fff;
            }
        """)
        self.passb.setEnabled(True)
        self.flagClose = False
        msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
            self, 
            'ВНИМАНИЕ', 
            'Процесс завершен - можете закрывать окно!'
        )

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self.flagClose:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'ВНИМАНИЕ', 
                'Не пытайтесь закрыть окно - выполняется процесс!'
            )
            event.ignore()
        else:
            event.accept()
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Dialog() #QtWidgets.QDialog()
    #ui = Ui_dialog()
    #ui.setupUi(dialog)
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Это можно сделать через флаги виджета, попробуйте так:

```
dialog.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)
```