# Как заблокировать закрытие окна в PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(240, 320)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 180, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "ok"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно что именно вы хотите сделать, уточните суть вопроса. Предполагаю что вам поможет это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1246645/457820

Comment: QWEWQ отвечает ли  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1246645   на ваш вопрос?

Comment: @S.Nick относительно, я просто вообще не понимаю как это работает, я пытался этот код подстроить под свою команду, но не получилось.

Comment: QWEWQ объясните лучше, для каких событий вы хотите заблокировать закрытие окна и каким событием вы все же будите закрывать окно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, можно сделать саму кнопку закрытия некликабельной. Только тогда `Form` сделать экземпляром `QMainWindow`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    Form.setWindowFlags(Form.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```